flutter: VideoPlayer initialization failed: PlatformException(VideoError, Failed to load video: Operation Stopped, null, null)
I used the video_player plugin. It works on Android, but it doesn't work on iOS simulator and real device, I tried all the ways.
Also, the following test videos open on iOS, for example: 'https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/butterfly.mp4', but my video URL does not open on iOS. Can you help?

Hello and welcome! You should at least provide the URL that fails (or another fake URL that fails if you cannot share your URL), so that we can understand what's the difference with the test URL that works.

Hello. It is a link with .mp4 extension coming from the API service and opens normally in the browser.
